# Cannot add header value to HTTP request via hooks

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Using Testcafe, I am trying to add an HTTP Header key/value pair to all my requests, but it is not appearing in the request header when I inspect the network request in-browser in Live mode.

I'm wondering if it's potentially an issue with TypeScript maybe? I had to modify the example code in documentation to allow method arguments to be of type `any` in order to get it to compile, which was surprising, because I haven't seen that requirement elsewhere, TC just 'handles' it.

Two questions, then:

- I am expecting to see the header `wafAccessToken` pair to appear in the request to `http://www.google.com`, but it isn't - any idea what could be the problem?
- Is there a way I can have my `RequestHook` not specify the exact URL in the constructor? I just want it to match and modify every request regardless of where I'm going.

Here is the code:

```
import { RequestHook } from 'testcafe';

export class WebSwitchHook extends RequestHook
{
    constructor(requestFilterRules: any, responseEventConfigureOpts: any)
    {
      super(requestFilterRules, responseEventConfigureOpts);
      // ...
    }

    async onRequest (e: any)
    {
      e.requestOptions.headers['wafAccessToken'] = "REDACTED";
      console.log(e.requestOptions);
    }

    async onResponse (e: any) {
      console.log(e.body);
    }
}

const webSwitchHook = new WebSwitchHook("http://www.google.com", {
  includeHeaders: true,
  includeBody: true
});

fixture.only('Test')
.page("http://www.google.com")
.requestHooks(webSwitchHook);

test('Test', async t => {
  
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you shared works correctly. You can see the headers you added on the server. You can also attach [RequestLogger](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html#log-http-requests) to the fixture and see the updated headers there.

As for your second question, you can use the code from [this example](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html#create-a-custom-request-hook) to use the `RequestHook` for all requests:

```
class JwtBearerAuthorization extends RequestHook {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    //...
}
```

Or, pass a regular expression to the RequestHook constructor to use it only for matching URLs.

Comment: Thank you for confirming - unfortunately the header is still not inserted for me when I run the code. Not sure why that might be...

Comment: @njp, Have you tried `RequestLogger` to check for headers? The headers are attached after the request is raised from the browser, so they will not be present in the `Network` tab of the browser's DevTools.